# Timezone doesn't change after update to Asia/Tehran in CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, date, time, centos

I have changed server timezone with following commands :

```
cp /etc/localtime /root/old.timezone
rm /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran /etc/localtime
```

but When I check server timezone it shows :

```
$ date
---------

Wed Apr 22 08:15:03 UTC 2015
```

which is wrong.

also `/etc/localtime` out put is :

```
TZif2UTCTZif2UTC
UTC0
```

How do I change server timezone?

```
OS : CentOS

Version : 6.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a CentOS 6.6 and I did as follow

```
# mv localtime localtime.old
# date
Thu Apr 23 13:14:36 UTC 2015

# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran /etc/localtime

# ll localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 31 Apr 23 17:45 localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran

# date
Thu Apr 23 17:45:36 IRDT 2015
```

as you see it did work prefect for me, I did all these change with root user